# Dev Tools showing CSS font correctly but incorrect font is showing

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts, google-webfonts

Wordpress is not showing the correct font on the site title. 
When I inspect, it is showing that it has the correct font (Tangerine) applied, but that's not actually the font showing on the page.

To make it more interesting, the computer I work on, shows everything correctly, even after logging out, deleting cookies, clearing cache, but my phone and other computer just show a serif font and not the cursive Google font Tangerine.

Here's what inspect shows.

[image]

The font actually shows up like this though:

[image]

and it should look like this (this is how it looks on chrome on the computer where I added the custom css to the wordpress theme hestia).

[image]

Comment: Any errors in the console ?

Comment: Would you mind sharing a link to your site?

Comment: Where do you define the `Tangerine` font in your CSS? I mean the URL from where the font should be loaded? Maybe you have it locally installed on your PC and that's why you can see it there.

Comment: Thank you all so much for your help and looking at this. I really appreciate it. I barely ever post here because I can almost always find what I need through a good google search. This one had me baffled. I'm actually using the google font's plugin and wanted the Tangerine just for the main heading but not for all headings and figured it was easier to do custom css for the main heading than having to do it for all the other headings. I just realized I was able to change this under advanced settings. I apologize for taking your time and thank you again so much for looking at this question. :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe forget to import google font into your website

on DEV tools they looking same

looking below

```css
span{
      font-family: 'Tangerine', cursive;
    }
```

```html
<span>hello word - not import</span>
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Tangerine&display=swap');
    span{
      font-family: 'Tangerine', cursive;
    }
```

```html
<span>hello word - import</span>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for looking at this. I left a comment above as to what had happened. I really appreciate your help :)